# Trying to move Users And Program Files Directories to Another Partition

Tags: windows-7, filesystems, ntfs

Currently I've Followed [this](http://lifehacker.com/5467758/move-the-users-directory-in-windows-7) guide.

I pointed my `C:\Users`, `C:\Program Files (x86)`, and `C:\Program Files` directories to their respective counterparts on the B: drive.

I used `mklink /J D:\Users B:\Users` (D was the C: drives name in recovery) but when the computer boots, all I get is that the profile can't be loaded.

I have to accomplish this, and don't really mind reinstalling as its a fresh install anyway.